# Three dots on JavaScript problem while creating new objects that inherit from a existing one

Tags: javascript, object, syntax

Let's say i have

```js
const adrian = {
    fullName: 'Adrian Oprea',
    occupation: 'Software developer',
    age: 31,
    website: 'https://oprea.rocks'
};

const bill = {
    ...adrian,
    fullName: 'Bill Gates',
    website: 'https://microsoft.com'
};

console.log(bill.fullName)
```

I read on a website (https://oprearocks.medium.com/what-do-the-three-dots-mean-in-javascript-bc5749439c9a) that `...adrian,` would give the object `bill` the same properties of `adrian`. But when I try to execute the code, this error occurs:

```
    ...adrian,
    ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
```

Am I missing something to make this work?

Comment: Where are you running this code?

Comment: On VSCode using node and on Codecademy page.

Comment: What version of node?

Comment: I'm using node v6.11.2, maybe need to update?

Comment: Yes. Older version that doesn't support the feature. You can open browser dev tools console right here on this page , paste that code into it and see the expected results in the console log assuming you are  using a modern browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the node version that I was using in VSCode, basically I just needed to update from v6.11.2 (long time ago, lol) to v14.17.3, thanks again  @charlietfl